# C# XML Serialization exclude writing class name

Tags: c#, .net, xml

The layout I'm going for is like the below layout (this is part of a bigger structure):

```
       <Products>
            <R001 Retail=\"2.289\" Rank=\"1\" Code=\"001\" />
            <R002 Retail=\"2.289\" Rank=\"2\" Code=\"002\" />
            <R003 Retail=\"2.889\" Rank=\"3\" Code=\"003\" />
            <R004 Retail=\"0\" Rank=\"4\" Code=\"0\" />
            <R011 Retail=\"0\" Rank=\"7\" Code=\"0\" />
        </Products>
```

So I have a class that has a property called Products. That property is a list of a class I call ProductExport. ProductExport has 3 properties that I mark with the XmlAttribute attribute and they are called Retail, Rank, Code. In ProductExport I implement IXmlSerializable so I can implement WriteXml() in which I make the tag names those R00X tags. That all works fine, however since ProductExport is it's own class the XmlSerializer writes a tag for each ProductExport in the list. I don't want a ProductExport tag. I would have thought by implementing IXmlSerializable on ProductExport I would control everything about how a ProductExport gets written, including NOT writing it's class name, but it seems to not be the case. How do I restrict writing it's class name?

```
public class StoresExport
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public int DistrictID { get; set; }
        public int? RegionID { get; set; }
        public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
        public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
        public List<CompetitorLocation> RelatedLocations { get; set; }
        public List<ProductExport> Products { get; set; }
    }



public class ProductExport : IXmlSerializable
    {
        public float Retail { get; set; }
        public int Rank { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }

        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            // we aren't ever reading just writing
        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("R" + Code);

            writer.WriteAttributeString("Retail", Retail.ToString());
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Rank", Rank.ToString());
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Code", Code);

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
```

With that code this is the output which I don't want:

```
<Products>
            <ProductExport>
                <R001 Retail=\"0\" Rank=\"1\" Code=\"001\" />
            </ProductExport>
            <ProductExport>
                <R002 Retail=\"0\" Rank=\"2\" Code=\"002\" />
            </ProductExport>
            <ProductExport>
                <R003 Retail=\"0\" Rank=\"3\" Code=\"003\" />
            </ProductExport>
            <ProductExport>
                <R004 Retail=\"0\" Rank=\"4\" Code=\"004\" />
            </ProductExport>
            <ProductExport>
                <R011 Retail=\"0\" Rank=\"7\" Code=\"011\" />
            </ProductExport>
        </Products>
```

Comment: I'd really prefer not to have to implement IXmlSerializable on the StoreExports class as the other attributes export just fine and it would be more typing than needed so a suppression of the ProductExport tag would be more ideal if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.writexml(v=vs.110).aspx), it's the parent element that will write the start and end elements for `ProductExport`:

> The WriteXml implementation you provide should write out the XML representation of the object. **The framework writes a wrapper element** and positions the XML writer after its start. **Your implementation may write its contents**, including child elements. **The framework then closes the wrapper element**.

So to do this, you need to write the element name you want within `Products`. The simplest way to do this is to replace the `List<ProductExport>` with your own class that also implements `IXmlSerializable`.

When this is serialized, the framework will have already written the `Product` element (and will close it after), so, sticking with the contract, all you have to write is the start and end elements for each of your items and delegate the writing of their content to their implementation of `IXmlSerializable`:

```
public class Products : IXmlSerializable, IEnumerable<ProductExport>
{
    private readonly List<ProductExport> _products = new List<ProductExport>();

    public void Add(ProductExport product) => _products.Add(product);

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() => null;    

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (var product in this)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("R" + product.Code);
            product.WriteXml(writer);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }        
    }

    public IEnumerator<ProductExport> GetEnumerator() => _products.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dyBdwp) for a working demo.

Comment: Strange, so in Products you're calling the ProductExports implementation of WriteXml(). So the Serializer won't call that on it's own also since ProductExport also implements Serializer?

Comment: @user441521 the framework won't do anything for any members of `Products` because you've removed control from the framework by implementing `IXmlSerializable`.

Comment: Don't get me wrong this works great, but I'm still just confused. The framework is calling WriteXml() since I've implemented IXmlSerializable. It's calling it on Products. Why isn't it calling it on ProductExport? We explicitly call it from Products but I would think the frameworks sees that we implement it on ProductExport as well and call it there too. So I would think WriteXml() would get called twice for ProductExport. Once from the framework since it sees we implemented it on ProductExport and once from us in Product where we manually call it on each ProductExport.

Comment: @user441521 the framework has delegated any and all interaction with the `XmlWriter` to the `IXmlSerializable` implementation. You have complete control as to what is written for the content of `Products` at this point.  You could ignore the products entirely and [write some garbage in there](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JuovEQ); the framework no longer has any say in what to write, only you do.

Comment: I understand that part. I get that I can write whatever I want when I implement IXmlSerializable but the framework IS calling the WriteXml() function since I implemented that interface. I'm asking about why isn't the framework calling WriteXml() on ProductExport class? We implemented it there too.

Comment: @user441521 Why would it? The framework is never asked to serialize a `ProductExport`. The only reason the contents of a `ProductExport` are written is because you explicitly wrote the code to make that happen. `ProductExport` doesn't really need to implement `IXmlSerializable`, you *could* put all the code inside `Products` if you wanted.

Comment: @user441521 if you get that you can write whatever I want when you implement IXmlSerializable, then surely you must get that if you write nothing then nothing will get written?

Comment: Oh OK. Since this class was a child of a class I said to export I assumed the framework would look at all child classes and see if they implement IXmlSerializable and call their functions too. When Products was a list of ProductExport's in my first example that's what it did because inside ProductExports I implemented IXmlSerializable and it called WriteXml() automatically for me..(not a child but contained within it)

Comment: If you look in my example I'm actually telling the Serializer to serialize StoreExports which doesn't implement IXmlSerialize, but one class inside of it that does implement that interface gets called. So I would assume all classes inside that implement that interface would get that their WriteXml() function called by the framework. It's a little confusing to me I guess.

Comment: @user441521 in that context, the *framework* is responsible for serialising `StoreExports`. In this context, *you* are responsible for serialising `Products` (or, more accurately, the *content* of `Products`) as you implemented `IXmlSerializable`. That's the difference.

Comment: OK, I think I get it. If a class implements from IXmlSerializable then whatever it contains the framework won't try to Serialize it. It's up to you. So if you have a class that contains a class that contains a class and you implement IXmlSerializable at the first class, it's up to us to chain it down the rest of the way. So basically the first time it hits a class that implements IXmlSerializable it's up to you to write out anything else that class may contain, even if it's other classes.